# Making a character string with column names with zero values

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, grepl

The 4th column is my desired column. Video,Webinar,Meeting,Conference are the 4 type of activities that the different customers(names) can engage in. You can see,in a given row, all the column names with zero value are in the final column(NextStep) and the value there(character string separated by commas) excludes the column name with non-zero value. The character strings(column names) in the final column usually appear in the column order with two exceptions. Webinar always appears first if it has a zero value and video always appears last if it has a zero value.

```
    library(data.table)
     dt <- fread('
 Name     Video   Webinar Meeting Conference   NextStep
  John       1         0        0       0         Webinar,Meeting,Conference
  John       1         1        0       0         Meeting,Conference
  John       1         1        1       0         Conference      
  Tom        0         0        1       0         Webinar,Conference,Video
  Tom        0         0        1       1         Webinar,Video   
  Kyle       0         0        0       1         Webinar,Meeting,Video

                                    ')
```

My question is how to create the next step column. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: .. and your question is, how to create column `NextStep`? And what is `dt[, Date := as.IDate(Date)]` for?

Comment: Yes, it is how to create the next step column.

Comment: Please include an explicit question in your post

Comment: @docendodiscimus I apologize. It was there for a date field that is not relevant in this case of this question.

Comment: no problem, looks good now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
DT[, nextstep := paste0(names(.SD)[.SD==0], collapse = ','), 1:nrow(DT), .SDcols = 2:5][]
```

which gives:

```
   Name Video Webinar Meeting Conference                   nextstep
1: John     1       0       0          0 Webinar,Meeting,Conference
2: John     1       1       0          0         Meeting,Conference
3: John     1       1       1          0                 Conference
4:  Tom     0       0       1          0   Video,Webinar,Conference
5:  Tom     0       0       1          1              Video,Webinar
6: Kyle     0       0       0          1      Video,Webinar,Meeting
```

---

When you want to order the names as you specified in the comments, you can do:

```
lvls <- c('Webinar', 'Meeting', 'Conference', 'Video')
DT[, nextstep := paste0(lvls[lvls %in% names(.SD)[.SD==0]], collapse = ','), 
   1:nrow(DT), .SDcols = 2:5][]
```

which gives:

```
   Name Video Webinar Meeting Conference                   nextstep
1: John     1       0       0          0 Webinar,Meeting,Conference
2: John     1       1       0          0         Meeting,Conference
3: John     1       1       1          0                 Conference
4:  Tom     0       0       1          0   Webinar,Conference,Video
5:  Tom     0       0       1          1              Webinar,Video
6: Kyle     0       0       0          1      Webinar,Meeting,Video
```

Instead of using `paste0` (with `collapse = ','`) you can also use `toString`.

---

Used data:

```
DT <- fread('Name     Video   Webinar  Meeting  Conference
             John       1         0        0        0
             John       1         1        0        0
             John       1         1        1        0
             Tom        0         0        1        0
             Tom        0         0        1        1
             Kyle       0         0        0        1')
```

Comment: Thank you for the awesome solution. Is there any way to make Webinar always appear first and Video always appear last in the nextstep2 field?

Comment: @gibbz00 and what about 'Meeting' and 'Conference'?

Comment: In the case of meeting and conference, we can resort to the column order where meeting comes before conference

Answer (score 4):

In case you are looking for a way to do this without simply re-ordering the columns in the order you want (in fact I see no reason why not to do so, but anyway..) you could try the following approach. It `melt`s and updates by reference in a join:

```
lvls <- c("Webinar", "Meeting", "Conference", "Video")  # make sure order is correct
dt[, row := .I]   # add a row-identifier
dtm <- melt(dt, id.vars = c("Name", "row"), measure.vars = lvls) # melt to long format
# summarise dtm by using factor, sorting it and converting to strin; then join to dt
dt[dtm[value == 0, list(NextStep2 = toString(sort(factor(variable, levels = lvls)))), 
    by = row], NextStep2 := NextStep2, on = "row"][, row := NULL]

#    Name Video Webinar Meeting Conference                   NextStep                    NextStep2
# 1: John     1       0       0          0 Webinar,Meeting,Conference Webinar, Meeting, Conference
# 2: John     1       1       0          0         Meeting,Conference          Meeting, Conference
# 3: John     1       1       1          0                 Conference                   Conference
# 4:  Tom     0       0       1          0   Webinar,Conference,Video   Webinar, Conference, Video
# 5:  Tom     0       0       1          1              Webinar,Video               Webinar, Video
# 6: Kyle     0       0       0          1      Webinar,Meeting,Video      Webinar, Meeting, Video
```

If you want to paste all column names as in the data for those cases where there's no activity, you can add the following line to your code:

```
dt[rowSums(dt[, mget(lvls)]) == 0, NextStep2 := toString(names(dt)[2:5])]
```

Comment: Thank you for the great solution. For someone who has not any activity, so all the column are zero, in that case I want to do video,webinar,meeting,conference just as the column order appears in the original dataframe.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
setcolorder(dt, c("Name", "Webinar", "Meeting", "Conference", "Video", "NextStep"))
dt[, NextStepNew:=apply(dt, 1, function(x) paste0(names(x)[x==0], collapse=","))][]
   Name Webinar Meeting Conference Video                   NextStep                NextStepNew
1: John       0       0          0     1 Webinar,Meeting,Conference Webinar,Meeting,Conference
2: John       1       0          0     1         Meeting,Conference         Meeting,Conference
3: John       1       1          0     1                 Conference                 Conference
4:  Tom       0       1          0     0   Webinar,Conference,Video   Webinar,Conference,Video
5:  Tom       0       1          1     0              Webinar,Video              Webinar,Video
6: Kyle       0       0          1     0      Webinar,Meeting,Video      Webinar,Meeting,Video
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!