# How to reshape data with 0 and 1 in cells to have only cells with 1

Tags: r, multiple-columns, reshape

I have data in the following format:

```
datetime <- c('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-01 00:01:00', '2016-01-01 00:02:00',....)
D1 <- c(1, 1, 0, ...)
D2 <- c(0, 1, 0, ...)
D3 <- c(1, 0, 0, ...)
df <- data.frame(datetime,D1,D2,D3)
```

Basically, I have several columns with 1 & 0 at successive time stamps.

TO DO:

I want to generate a new dataframe with 2 columns: the dateTime stamp, and a single column with the names of all columns which are non-zero at that time.

TRIED SO FAR:

I can use reshape to convert the first dataframe from long to wide format, then remove rows with 0.

```
molten <- melt(df, id = c("datetime"))
new <- subset(molten, molten$value > 0)
```

QUERY:

Now, how to convert it into the following format?

```
dateTime <- c('2016-01-01 00:00:00','2016-01-01 00:01:00', '2016-01-01 00:02:00',....)
D <- c('D1,D3' , 'D1,D2', '', ...)
new_df <- data.frame(dateTime,D)
```

And how to avoid loss of time stamp information that occurs upon subsetting ?
(notice that the 3rd timestamp has an NA value as D1,D2 & D3 are all '0' at that time)

Comment: Related: [*Making a character string with column names with zero values*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37734904/2204410)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution :

```
cn <- colnames(df)[-1]
new_df <- cbind(df['datetime'],
                D=apply( df[,-1] != 0, 1 , function(x) paste(cn[x],collapse=',')))

> new_df
             dateTime     D
1 2016-01-01 00:00:00 D1,D3
2 2016-01-01 00:01:00 D1,D2
3 2016-01-01 00:02:00
```

Explanation :

- we store the colnames (excluding `dateTime`) into a vector called `cn`
- `df[,-1] != 0` returns a matrix of `TRUE/FALSE` being TRUE where different 
  from zero
- using `apply` for each row of the previous matrix we subset `cn` using the values `TRUE/FALSE` and we collapse the resulting colnames into one string
- then we bind the previous data.frame (only the `dateTime` column actually) with the new values into a column called `D`